# Testing FireBaseAuth and firebaseFireStore in testing module

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my project for authentication and FireStore, I am new to testing and I want to test that my data is being being downloaded (I am using firestore as both my local and remote data source since it support caching), my project is a multi module one, I have a data layer modules and UI layer modules, I added a testing module and added all the relevant dependencies by the documentation, I am trying to inject to my test a use case which receives FirebaseAuth and Firebase Firestore in it (and does its magic downloading the data and saving it locally).
when I run my test it says:

```
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first
```

as far as I understand, and in my project I do not initialize it (in the Application class and anywhere, and it works), as far as I understand from reading the documentation

> initializing "by hand" Firebase app is not necessary

this are the dependencies in the testing gradle that are of Firebase:

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.8.1")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.6.0")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.0")
```

I have created addition google-service.json file for the testing module in the firestore console and added it in the corresponding place in the testing module, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, also read the documentation several times and I added all that is necessary for Firebase,
would be glad for some insight of what I may be doing wrong?
thanks!